# Bison: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: syntax, bison

this is my thermo.l file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+                  return NUMBER;
heat                    return TOKHEAT;
on|off                  return STATE;
target                  return TOKTARGET;
temperature             return TOKTEMPERATURE;
\n                      /* ignore end of line */;
[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;
%%
```

This is my thermo.y file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 

main()
{
        yyparse();
} 

%}

%token NUMBER TOKHEAT STATE TOKTARGET TOKTEMPERATURE
```

THIS IS THE y.tab.h FILE

```
commands: /* empty */
        | commands command
        ;

command:
        heat_switch
        |
        target_set
        ;

heat_switch:
        TOKHEAT STATE
        {
                printf("\tHeat turned on or off\n");
        }
        ;

target_set:
        TOKTARGET TOKTEMPERATURE NUMBER
        {
                printf("\tTemperature set\n");
        }
        ;
```

I tried to compile my THERMO.Y file but its gives me an error.
"error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"
*Please note i'm using the Bison.

```
flex thermo.l
bison -y -d thermo.y
gcc -g -c lex.yy.c y.tab.c
gcc -g -0 thermo.n lex.yy.o y.tab.0 -ll
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I don't see any grammar in your thermo.y file. Have you left part of it out? If that is your entire file, I think bison will be asking the same question: Where is the grammar? :)

Comment: commands: /* empty */
        | commands command
        ;

command:
        heat_switch
        |
        target_set
        ;

heat_switch:
        TOKHEAT STATE
        {
                printf("\tHeat turned on or off\n");
        }
        ;

target_set:
        TOKTARGET TOKTEMPERATURE NUMBER
        {
                printf("\tTemperature set\n");
        }
        ;

Comment: Please edit your question. Code in comments is unreadable. Also clearly at what point in the compilation steps you receive the error message. (You can leave out the steps after the error, actually, since they are obviously not relevant.)

Comment: Yes accidentally I added here, Have edit the question. thanks.

Comment: The grammar is supposed to be part of the `.y` file; `y.tab.h` is produced by bison (and bison will cheerfully overwrite your file, so make sure you have a copy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar is supposed to be *part* of the `.y` file, as shown in the example in the [`bison` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Grammar-Outline.html#Grammar-Outline):

```
 %{
   Prologue
 %}

 Bison declarations

 %%
 Grammar rules
 %%

 Epilogue
```

The first `%%` and at least one Grammar rule are required; if you don't have them, you'll get an unexpected EOF error.

IMHO, you shouldn't be using the `-y` flag, but if you do, you'll find that `bison` overwrites your `y.tab.h` file.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this Lex and Yacc.. still figuring things out.. :(